# Angular-Google-Maps: How to use 'method' in the controller

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

When I change my app from jQuery way to Angular way,
I try to use Angular-Google-Maps.

But I can't find where is the Google Map Objects(Map, Marker, Polygon...) 
and the approach to use Object 'method' (such like getMap() , getPath(), getPosition()..).

If I need to get the position of the marker which is dragged, how can i do?
just like I usually do ?

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker(opts);
postion = marker.getPosition();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:**
I found a way how to get the marker position when it was dragged'n'dropped. You can set the callback function for the marker:

```
<google-map center="center" zoom="zoom" control="googleMap">
   <marker coords="coords" options="options" events="events">
</google-map>
```

Then in the controller you define the callback:

```
$scope.events: {
               dragend: function (marker) {
                  $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                     console.log(marker.position.lat());
                     console.log(marker.position.lng());
                  });
               }
            }
```

**Old Answer:**
It is currently not possible:
https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/issues/277

However, you can get the original google.maps.Map object:

Directive call:

```
<google-map center="center" zoom="zoom" control="googleMap"></google-map>
```

Angular controller:

```
...
$scope.center = = {
            latitude: 48.13171,
            longitude: 11.549554
         };
$scope.zoom = 8;
$scope.googleMap = {}; // this is filled when google map is initiated

function getMapObject() {
   $scope.googleMap.control.getGMap();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't even need events, the library already binds your marker position with the scope.

Here is how I did it in Coffee Script:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.map =
  center:
    latitude: k
    longitude: D
  zoom: 16
  marker:
    coord:
      k
      D
```

**View:**

```
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
      <ui-gmap-marker
              idKey="'pin'"
              coords="map.marker.coord"
              options="{'draggable':true}"
              >
      </ui-gmap-marker>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>

    <pre>{{map | json}}</pre>
```