# Displaying google maps in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, maps

I might be making a really silly mistake here, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Just trying to get a simple map to display on page with google maps and angular.js.

Here is my controller..

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApplicationModule', ['google-maps']);
myApp.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.map = {
    center: {
        latitude: 45,
        longitude: -73
    },
    zoom: 8
};
```

}]);

And here is my html page..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApplicationModule">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="IndexController">
    <google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom"></google-map>
    <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/lodash.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/angular-google-maps.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/angular.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have included all the necessary scripts and gotten angular.js from NuGet, declared my application and specified the controller.

However, the map is not displaying on the page.. Anybody able to point out why?

Comment: Where's the reference to *angular.js* ?

Comment: Sorry, edited to show this..

Comment: You need to have *angular.js* listed before *angular-google-maps.js*

Comment: Thanks, but still no joy.. Could it be auto hidden on start up or do I need to apply a style?

Comment: I don't think you need to apply a style.

Comment: Think I found your answer, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705447/angular-google-maps-does-now-show-correctly-when-its-hidden-at-start?rq=1

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid now, the answer was to include my controller in the script.. <script src='/Controllers/Index.js'></script>

Comment: m.e conroy, do you want to answer this so I can give some credit?

Comment: Nah, its ok. Thanks though, glad you found the problem